# What is his actual gain percent?

Tags: percentages

By selling balut at 12 pesos each a vendor gains 19.7%. The cost price of balut rises by 12.5%. If he sells the balut at the same price as before, what is his new gain in percent?

Comment: Peso is the currency of Argentina (If anybody got stuck at this word)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's best to find the original cost of the balut.  If that is $x$ then $12 = x \times 1.197$, in which case. $x = 10.025.$  Then if the cost goes up by $12.5\%,$ we have the new cost to be $10.025 \times 1.125 = 11.278.$

So if he still sells at $12$ pesos, the markup is $(12-11.278)/11.278 = 0.064$ or $6.4\%.$

Comment: Thank you so much...☺

Comment: Thanks a lot ..☺